# json file and $.getJSON

Tags: php, json, jquery

I am trying to get the json file using $.getJSON by using:

```
$.getJSON('json/resume.json', function(data){
    alert('success');
});
```

but the alert message is not coming, i tried by:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'json/download.php',
}).success(function(){alert("hello")});
```

in this case the alert is coming as HELLO.

I am totally stuck.
please help

Thanks

Comment: did u use dev tools in browser and check the NET tab for server 500 errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should checkout error which happens in your getJSON(), e.g.

```
$.getJSON('json/resume.json', function(data){
    alert('success');
}).error(function(e, m) { alert('error'); console.log(m); });
```

Comment: yes. it says parsererror in the console. and alerts the message 'error'. what is the work around?

Comment: As guys already said it's json format error. Maybe you should post json-file contents so as to understand whats wrong with it.

Comment: i am getting the parseerror but at the same time i am getting the response correctly.

Comment: What response did you get correctly? In your second example, via ajx call to download.php?

Comment: this is the link to my json file https://www.dropbox.com/s/nv95pkt2dthd4ln/resume.json

Comment: no i modified the ajax call: "$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'json/resume.json',
  beforeSend: function(x) {
     if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
       x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
     }
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
    alert("success");
   }
   
 }).error(function(e, m) { alert('error'); console.log(m); })":: i am getting the parseerror in the console and the control is not going to success method. the code i am getting is 304

Comment: Check out string `"state": "Tamil Nadu",`, there shouldn't be comma in the end of it as it's the last element of array.

Answer (score 2):

You are using two different requests to two different urls and comparing them as if the same, the first is get to json/resume.json and the second is POST to json/download.php. The only reason the first call would fail is either one of these:

```
json/resume.json does not exist
json/resume.json does not contain valid json
```

You need to either set global ajax error handlers so that you will get your error from getJSON, or run the same json query through an ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json/resume.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)//should come into console anyway 
    },
    error: function(request, type, errorThrown) {

        message = (type=='parseerror') ? "json is invalid" : "(" + request.status + " " + request.statusText + ").";
        alert("error with request: "+message);
    }
})
```

Comment: i even used '$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'json/resume.json',
}).success(function(){alert("hello")});
'

Answer (score 0):

the first is a GET, the second is a POST - did u use dev tools in browser and check the NET tab for server 500 errors?

if your server method is only accepting POSTs that's your bother right there.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side script doesn't return valid JSON or doesn't set the `Content-Type` response header to `application/json`.

So make sure those 2 conditions are met before attempting to consume your script with `$.getJSON`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: i have a separate json file whose value is what i want. but i am not able to get it. i thought that there must be something wrong with the path that i am giving, so i tried to alert a message by giving a php path, and it worked. how to get it work?